# Why are gorilla chest beats so high-pitched?

Tags: fictional-sounds, mammals

I am surprised by the relatively high pitch of Gorilla chest drumming (listen [here)](https://youtu.be/lc-2EbIEmwM), which peak frequency [ranges between 0.6-0.7 Hz](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-021-86261-8#data-availability). Actually, they sound like human-cheek drumming (listen [here](https://youtu.be/aYN4sT0Z-UE))!!

When a human beats their own chest, this sounds far lower pitch than gorilla (but far quieter I agree...). While human-cheek drumming peak frequency is related to those of vocal track formants, [gorilla chest beating peak frequency is related to body size (Wright et al 2021)](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-021-86261-8#data-availability),
[image]
but the exact involved resonators seem unknown according to them:

> Our measure of body size, back breadth, likely correlates with a range
> of morphological traits, including chest volume, pulmonary capacity
> and hand size. Therefore it is unclear which specific trait or traits
> are responsible for driving the inverse relationship between back
> breadth and peak frequency. Moreover, gorillas like other non- human
> primates possess laryngeal air sacs which are thought to act as
> resonators, enhancing acoustic signals4,11,24. Indeed, gorillas appear
> to use laryngeal air sacs during growling vocalizations which often
> accompany chest beating24. The volume of laryngeal air sacs is likely
> to be directly correlated with body size, at least within-species
> (which in orangutans (Pongo) can reach a massive 6 L38). Thus larger
> males are expected to have larger laryngeal air sacs than smaller
> males, further lowering the resonating non-vocal frequencies produced
> whilst chest beating. However, our knowledge of the size and function
> of laryngeal air sacs in primates and other taxa remains poor39.

Anyone knows more about it here?

Actually, the only reason why I'm asking this question is probably to be found in [King-Kong low-pitch chest beat sound](https://youtu.be/eojSvHhcNmo), I'm sorry :-D.